# Integrate Magit with ssh-ident

Tags: magit, ssh

Recently I was looking at utilities for handling ssh-agent at an even higher level, so that entering SSH keys passphrases becomes even more seamless than with the standard ssh-agent utility.

One such utility is [ssh-ident](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident), the one I chose as the best solution for my workflow. I have configured my system paths so that Git uses ssh-ident instead of regular ssh, which is what the utility requires in order to work.

However, whenever I have to enter an SSH key passphrase through Magit, I get stuck because Magit does not parse the prompt that this tool issues. I would like to know if it is possible to fix this issue (or, in general, of any solution to have ssh-ident work w/ Magit).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update:

Magit now supports prompting for the password in the way that ssh-ident asks for it by default, via the variable `magit-process-password-prompt-regexps`. In my case, I had to adjust it as follows:

```lisp
;; Integrate with ssh-ident
(add-to-list 'magit-process-password-prompt-regexps
             "^\\(Enter \\)?[Pp]assphrase for [^ ]*: ?$")
(add-to-list 'magit-process-password-prompt-regexps
             "^Bad passphrase, try again for [^ ]*: ?$")
```

---

#### Old:

I created the [emacs-ssh-ident](https://github.com/arthurcgusmao/emacs-ssh-ident) minor mode that adds a hook to Magit when it needs credentials and gets user input for ssh-ident.